# Google maps - apply grayscale custom styling to terrain view

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I made something like this:

http://static.cmslog.com/testapp/google/terrain

What I want to achieve now is terrain map with grayscale styling like here:

http://static.cmslog.com/testapp/google/maps

For now I applied the same rules (saturation: -100 for all), but it doesn't work. I can't also achieve this effect here:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Does anyone know, how to make terrain map in grayscale so it looks like this image:

[image: grayscale terrain map]

I didn't provide any code, as all I have is under links pasted above.

Also [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076820/google-maps-using-custom-json-styling-and-terrain-view) doesn't work :/

- Sorry if links above will stop working after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear that Google do not allow [do not have the capability for] the terrain map tiles to show the land as styled. You can style everything but the land itself.

So: can't be done. The Terms of Service only allow you to do what the API is capable of, and it can't style the land in terrain maps.

Answer (score 0):

According to what @Andrew Leach wrote, the only way to do it, is to convert terrain map images to grayscale (i.e. in PHP) and cache them in your own server. Then you can replace them in HTML, as I made it here:

http://static.cmslog.com/testapp/google/terrain-tweak

EDIT:
But as it's stated in comment below it's against ToS, so it can't be done in this way, and link is down now.

Comment: I wrote what I wrote very carefully. Creating derivative images is against the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), I'm afraid. See 10.1.3(a)(i).